# NodeJs access root owned file without root

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I have a nodejs server that runs on Ubuntu.
I need to modify a root-owned file.

I don't want to give the service root access.

Is there any way to give the node user root access for a specific file?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not change the permissions on the file?

Comment: No, I can not    .

Comment: Using sudo along with visudo is another option

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```sh
chmod o+rwx yourfile
```

will grant read/write/execute permissions to all other users

Answer (score 0):

replace with your NodePath

```
sudo chown root:www-data /root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node
sudo chmod 750 /root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node
```

show your  NodePath `which node`